# How do I get the row number of some text from input file?

Tags: java, arrays, database, search, inverted-index

I have some question below:

If there is a example database.txt as follow, how do I get the row number of certain number? For example, the number "1" appears in row 1, 3, 5, then i want to build an array which is [a]:[1 0 1 0 0 0 1], the 1 means item "1" appears in that row. Please Help!

Example Database.txt:

```
1 5
2 7
3 1
4 2
5 3
6 5
7 1
```

Comment: Use a counter when you read the file, increment each time you read a new line; Use a [`LineNumberReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html) or [`LineNumberInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberInputStream.html)

Comment: OK!! I will try it out, I just learn Java recently, thanks for help!
Start to learn Coding!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to build a 2 dimensional array.
the array would be for example array[7][2]. Then you would assign the numbers to the following array.
After that you would make a method and have 2 for loops.
1 for loop will track the rows and the other will track columns.

```
public int arrayMethod(array[][] a)
for(int row=0; row <= a.length; row++){
    for(int col=0; col<=a.length-1; col ++){
 if(array[row][col]== 1)
    {
    return 1;
    }
 else return 0;
}
   }
```

It should be something along the lines of this.

Comment: Great!! I was wondering how to store the occurrence of each item in each row. Using for loop with 2 dimension !!good I will try it out! Thank you :D